# Does a RFID Tag ID (TID) have a CRC?

Tags: checksum, rfid, crc

I was looking at the [GS1 Tag Data Standard](https://www.gs1.org/standards/epcrfid-epcis-id-keys/epc-rfid-tds/1-13) and noticed the EPC has a CRC-16. However, the unique tag ID (TID), specified in Section 16, **does not**.

Is that the case there is no checksum on the Tag ID? If so, what is the suggested method to ensure the tag ID that is read is in fact the actual value and that no bits were flipped?

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer from another message board. I'll post a summary here.
I was focused on the "StoredCRC" defined in the Memory spec mentioned above. However, I was pointed to the [Air Interface spec](https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/uhfc1g2_2_0_0_standard_20131101.pdf). In there, it defines both the StoredCRC as well as the PacketCRC. The latter is used for many interrogator->tag and tag->interrogator messages.

Some notable references in that spec:

- Section 6.3.1.5 gave a nice overview
- Section 6.3.2.1.2.1 described how StoredCRC and PacketCRC are managed/used
- Table 6.17 and Table 6.28 were good examples of the structure